# Tensor over projective $R$-modules remain projective

Tags: rt.representation-theory

It is known that if $R$ is a commutative module and P_1, P_2 are $R$ projective then $P_1\otimes P_2$ is again projective. Now, if $P$ is projective and $X$ is any, and $P\otimes X$ is projective, does it follow that $X$ is projective? Any countexamples?

Comment: Take $X$ non projective and $P=0$.

Answer (score 4):

(Edited after Johannes Hahn's comment.)

We need to assume that $P$ has positive rank at every maximal ideal to rule out examples like Fernando Muro's.

1)  Suppose $R$ is local.  Then $P$ and $P\otimes X$ are free. Write $P\approx R^n$ with $n>0$. Then $X^n\approx P\otimes X$ is free.  Because $n>0$, $X$ is a direct summand of the free module $X^n$ and hence free.

2)  More generally, $X$ is projective if and only if it becomes free after localizing at any maximal ideal, so  $X$ is projective by 1).

Comment: Wait, why is $F\otimes X = (P\oplus P')\otimes X$ projective? Only $P\otimes X$ is assumed to be projective, $P'\otimes X$ isn'.

Comment: @JohannesHahn:  I think this is fixed now.